# display the selected value from DropDown in a page

Tags: drop-down-menu

Hi Folks i am retrieving Name from database to drop down list. Now i want to display the selected value from DropDown in a page. My code is like follows to retrieve data,am using Fluent data as a framework.

My Controller Action is

```
var query = Abc.GetProducts();

ViewBag.EnterpriseId = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "EnterpriseId", "Name");
return View();
```

My view is ,
@Html.DropDownList("EnterpriseID", (SelectList) ViewBag.EnterpriseID, "--Select Resource--")

Comment: What language is that? Please add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple js for this:

```
elem = $('.selectClass');
options = elem.find('option[value="'+DataFromDBHere+'"]');
if(options){
 options.prop('selected', 'selected');
}
```